# Regular expression to match trading pair in a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract trading pairs from a sentence. A trading pair is two stock tickers plus a `/` between them, such as: `GME/USD`
I'd like write a regexp for browsers (Javascript) that picks up both the GBP and the USD pair.

Here are some sample sentences:

> Tomorrow MetaTrade lists the GME/USD and the GME/GBP pairs

> Tomorrow MetaTrade lists the TSLA/USD and the TSLA/GBP pairs

I currently have this:  `(.*)\/USD` but it matches all up to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Use `\w+/(?:USD|GBP)`

Comment: Related: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/123757

Comment: Something like `/\b([A-Z]{3})\/([A-Z]{3})\b/g` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. [Online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpshuA/1/)

```
\b\w+\/(?:USD|GBP)\b
```

Complete regex in JS will be:

```
/\b\w+\/(?:USD|GBP)\b/g
```

***Explanation:*** Putting a word boundary then looking for `\w`(1 or more word characters), which is followed by a non-capturing group of `USD` or `GBP` keywords followed by a word boundary.